# How to get email id of customer who write feedback on play store

Tags: android, google-play

Hello I am android developer & published one android app on play store. Customers are giving feedback on play store, I am looking any way to find out email id of those customers.

Is it possible . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't. And that's good.

Every communication between developer and customer in Google Play Store is public. Unless the customer send you an E-Mail.

More: [View & analyze your app's ratings & reviews](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138230?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately that is not possible, that is private data.

You can [reply to their reviews](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2013/05/all-google-play-developers-can-now.html), but you cannot find out their email address.

Answer (score 0):

You can always talk to the people that make replies to your app and by that you show them your thankgiveness